# How to return next day with str condition in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

My input data as below

[image]

I want get output with rule:

1. If column "Type" == "Settlement" return Date Recieved + 2
2. If column "Type" == "Personal" return Date Recieved + 7
3. If column "Type" == "Cash" return Date Recieved + 1

My desire output as below:

[image]

Tks for all attentions & supports!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the dataframe is `df`, first make sure that the `Date Received` column is of `datetime`

```
df['Date Received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Received'])
```

Assuming that there are only those three types (`Settlement`, `Personal`, `Cash`), the following custom lambda function will do the work

```
df['Date Checked'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date Received'] + pd.Timedelta(days=2) if x['Type'] == 'Settlement' else x['Date Received'] + pd.Timedelta(days=7) if x['Type'] == 'Personal' else x['Date Received'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1), axis=1)

[Out]:
  Date Received        Type Date Checked
0    2022-09-09  Settlement   2022-09-11
1    2022-09-09    Personal   2022-09-16
2    2022-09-09        Cash   2022-09-10
```

Else, one might have to specify the `Cash` as follows

```
df['Date Checked'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date Received'] + pd.Timedelta(days=2) if x['Type'] == 'Settlement' else x['Date Received'] + pd.Timedelta(days=7) if x['Type'] == 'Personal' else x['Date Received'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1) if x['Type'] == 'Cash' else x['Date Received'], axis=1)

[Out]:
  Date Received        Type Date Checked
0    2022-09-09  Settlement   2022-09-11
1    2022-09-09    Personal   2022-09-16
2    2022-09-09        Cash   2022-09-10
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary, mapping your desired day addition to different types and then map them to your column using `list` and `map`.

```
df['Date Received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Received'])

change_dict = {
    'Settlement': pd.Timedelta(days=2),
    'Personal': pd.Timedelta(days=7),
    'Cash': pd.Timedelta(days=1),
}

df['Date Checked'] = list(map(lambda x, y: x + change_dict[y], df['Date Recieved'], df['Type']))
```

If you are also worried about performance, this solution using `list`, `map` and dict mapping is more efficient than using `.apply()` with `if-else`.

[image: runtime benchmark]

Comment: With `change_dict` like this, you can also write: `df['Date Checked'] = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, df['Date Received'], df['Type'].map(change_dict)))`. But perhaps even better, just make the `dict` values `2, 7, 1`, and use `x + pd.Timedelta(days=y)` instead of `x + y` to avoid repetition.

Comment: Thanks for these good points, depending on the preference these can surely be implemented.